# HPFortify Security Scan - complaining violation for hibernate criteria add

Tags: security

HP fortify Security Features OWASP Top 10 2013
A4 Insecure Direct Object References

Without proper access control, the method lazyListExitCause() in
CauseDAOImpl.java can execute a SQL statement on line 81 that contains an attacker-controlled primary key, thereby allowing the attacker to access unauthorized records.

**line 80** Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(CauseTO.class, "c");

**line 81** criteria.createAlias("exitList", "e").add(Restrictions.eq("c.id",
        exitCriteriaTO.getRefId()))

Comment: Any update will be helpful for me?  Thanks

Comment: let me know if i need to provide more details?